# how to enable video view in android studio xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-videoview

In android studio project, I need to enable video view,please tell me the correct view for showing videos in app.Like Imageview,TextView,Editview in "Kotlin".
I need the xml code.

Comment: `VideoView` is part of the framework classes and is available to you with any Android project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.example.myapplication.CustomVideoView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_opencamera"
    android:id="@+id/vdrecord"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"/>

  Then in your java Class

public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

private PlayPauseListener mListener;

public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setPlayPauseListener(PlayPauseListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    super.pause();
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPlay();
    }
}



public static interface PlayPauseListener {
    void onPlay();
    void onPause();
}
```

}

In your class where you want to use.

```
vdrecord.setPlayPauseListener(new CustomVideoView.PlayPauseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {

        }
    });
```